# What is the name of this operator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, terminology

I was using a projection algorithm and came across and operator $$[~]_{+}$$, can anyone tell me what is this operator called and what it represents?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be a universally accepted notation...more like something defined in context.  If you provide some context for its use, someone here will probably be able to clarify it.  A link to a passage which uses the notation might be a good idea.

Comment: sometimes it is:
$$x_+ = \max\{x,0\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes $[a,b]_{+}$ is used to denote the **anticommutator** of two elements a and b, while $[a,b]_{-}$ is then used for the commutator.

The commutator of two elements a and b of a ring (or any associative algebra) is defined by

$\{a,b\}=ab-ba=[a,b]_{-}$.

The anticommutator of two elements a and b of a ring or associative algebra is defined by

$\{a,b\}=ab+ba=[a,b]_{+}$.

The anticommutator can be used to define Clifford algebras and Jordan algebras, or in the derivation of the Dirac equation in particle physics.